# Showing null instead of throwing a zero division error by try-catch

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, try-catch

Why does this procedure return NULL when `count` and `sum` are both 0?

```
create procedure avgSalaryByPositions
as
begin
begin try  
    declare @sum int
    select @sum=sum(base_salary) from position
    declare @count int
    select @count=count(*) from position
    select @sum/@count
end try
begin catch
    select
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber  
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity  
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState  
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure  
        ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine  
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;  
end catch
end
```

and does not produce output like this?

```
create procedure blablabla
as
begin
BEGIN TRY  
    SELECT 1/0;  
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  
    SELECT  
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber  
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity  
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState  
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure  
        ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine  
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;  
END CATCH;  
end
GO  


exec blablabla
```

How to change the first procedure to act same as the second one when there is nothing in the table, meaning when `sum` and `count` are both 0?

Thanks.

Comment: Note that you can combine the `select`s like this `select @sum = sum(base_salary), @count = count(*) from position` or just `select sum(base_salary) / count(*) from position`. Note also that you will get integer division

Comment: Don't eat errors if you are not going to do anything with them. And don't convert errors into a resultset. Either don't catch or rethrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is nothing in the table then you have no *rows*.  In that case, the `SUM()` returns `NULL`, not `0`.

If you want an error to occur, then replace it with a value:

```
select @sum = coalesce(sum(base_salary), 0) from position;
```

The `count()` will still return `0`, so this should generate an error.

Note that `avg()` would be a more sensible way to do the calculation.

Comment: Thanks It works. I tried ```if (@sum = NULL) set @sum = 0``` before asking, but it didn't work. What's the problem?

Comment: @AlexJ `if (@sum IS NULL)` because you cannot compare null with anything

Comment: @AlexJ think of `null` as saying "unknown value"; you can't say `if unknown value=x then`... because it's unknown.